# Correctly styling Android Home Widget size

Tags: android, android-widget

I try to display up to three elements in my Home Widget according to how many rows a user expanded the widget to. (1-3 should be allowed)

So the height of each element should be the height of one row. The main goal would be that it looks correct on every device.

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_roundedcorners_white">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/article1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widget_margin"
        android:background="#0000ff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article1img"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/inner_widget_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article1Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/appwidget_title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article1Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        style="@style/Divider">
        <!--<View style="@style/Divider"/>-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/article2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widget_margin"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article2img"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35pt"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/inner_widget_margin"
            android:background="#ffffff">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article2Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/appwidget_title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article2Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        style="@style/Divider">
        <!--<View style="@style/Divider"/>-->
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/article3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/widget_margin"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article3img"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35pt"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/inner_widget_margin"
            android:background="#ffffff">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article3Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/appwidget_title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article3Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

with

```
<dimen name="widget_margin">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="inner_widget_margin">2dp</dimen>
```

and

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="12dp"/>
</shape>
```

I read [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html) that the height of one row should be about `40dp` which is why I set my `article1` - Layout to 40dp and my info to

```
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/news_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/news_widget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:previewImage="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="2700000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

But the result I get looks like this, having the widget on minHeight:

[image]

So obviously the height of one element in my layout differs a lot to the height of one grid-row on the screen.

What am I doing wrong or what is the canonical approach to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

`minHeight` and `minWidth` are hints and suggestions, not demands. There are hundreds of launchers with home screens, and none are required to honor your desired values or support that small of a height. Your requested sizes are roughly 8:1 aspect ratio; the actual size you got was closer to 3:1.

Your `AppWidgetProvider` subclass can override `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()` and examine the supplied `Bundle` to get an idea of the actual size of the app widget. It is not guaranteed that this will be called for every home screen, but it's your best shot. There are `OPTION_APPWIDGET_` keys on `AppWidgetManager` that can be in that `Bundle`. For a `Bundle` parameter named `newOptions`, you can try to access:

- `newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH)`
- `newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH)`
- `newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT)`
- `newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT)`

Those will be values in `dp`.

From there, you can use `AppWidgetManager` to send over a new `RemoteViews` that is perhaps better tailored for the size of the app widget as seen on the home screen.

[This old sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/AppWidget/Resize) demonstrates this, with an app widget that displays its own size ranges.

Comment: Thansk! What exactly means the min/max value. Does this really help me to resize the widget-content to the correct size? How do I know if I should resize content to min or max?

Comment: Also I am not sure how to change the height of my LinearLayouts. The docs say to use `LayoutParams.height` before Android 12 but I can't figure out how.

Comment: @progNewbie: "What exactly means the min/max value" -- it means that your app widget has an actual size within the range specified by the min and max values for width and height. "How do I know if I should resize content to min or max?" -- that would be a question for your graphic designer.

Comment: Okay, so one can not really know the exact size :/ 
Do you know how I can set the size of my RemoteViews?

Comment: @progNewbie: AFAIK, effectively, the `RemoteViews` itself is akin to a parent container set to `match_parent`/`match_parent` for the size, to fill whatever space the `RemoteViews` is applied to (the app widget, the custom `Notification`, etc.).